# Telegram Bot - Does chat id remain same for all the time?

Tags: telegram-bot

I am making a telegram bot, which requires a registration and further usage of bot's services, regularly updating user's data.
I have some cases, when I need to edit user's data, but all I can receive from chat is `chat.id`.

I am planning to use it as a unique value for identifying specifically that user.

The question is, does this attribute remain same for all the time user interacts with bot? I suppose that it will change, when user deletes chat, but will it change in other cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `chat.id` of a [Chat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat) between a bot and a [User](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) will never change.
 In this situation the `chat.id` represents the id of the [User](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user).